# Using arithmetic (other than foreach) to set label of nodes

Tags: counters

I'd like to use integer variables to set the text inside the label of nodes, BUT WITHOUT using foreach (because these variables have their value set according to some conditional processing)

Any clue?

Thanks in advance,
K.

Comment: What kind of nodes? TikZ nodes? Can you perhaps provide a minimal example with code similar to what you're after?

Answer (score 1):

If the variables only have integer values then you can do something like the following

```
\number\numexpr\varA+\varB*\varC\relax
```

But a bit more context might help here.

If you're using `TikZ` then you can use the math parser:

```
\pgfmathparse{<integer expression>}
```

and then later retrieve the value as

```
\pgfmathresult
```

Depending on how you want to use the result, I've found that it can help save the value in another macro as follows:

```
 \pgfmathsetmacro\mystoredvalue{<integer expression>}
```

or even

```
 \edef\mystoredvalue{\pgfmathresult}
```

If you're working with `pstricks` then you can use post script code to determine node positions.

Comment: Oh, thanks a lot! Indeed Tikz nodes was what I meant.
I think pgfmathparse & pgfmathresult are the good choice.
Karim

Comment: To save the value in a macro, I think that `\pgfmathsetmacro\mystoredvalue{<integer expression>}` is simpler...

Comment: @PaulGaborit I've occasionally had problems with expansion (particularly in a `\foreach` loop).